# Hoyw to resolve empty value in js

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem, Inside a loop I inject a button. When I click on the button, a value is returned.

My product.php

```php-template
<?php
  for ($i = 0, $n = \count($languages); $i < $n; $i++) {
?>
  <div class="row" id="productsSeoTitle<?php echo $i ?>">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group row" data-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <label for="<?php echo $Products->getDef('text_products_page_title'); ?>" class="col-1 col-form-label">
          <?php echo $CLICSHOPPING_Products->getDef('text_products_page_title'); ?>
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-4 input-group" id="products_head_title_tag<?php echo $i; ?>">
          <?php 
          echo '&nbsp;' 
             . HTML::inputField('products_head_title_tag[' . $languages[$i]['id'] . ']'
                      , SeoAdmin::getProductsSeoTitle($pInfo->products_id, $languages[$i]['id'])
                      , 'maxlength="70" size="77" id="products_head_title_tag_' . $i 
                        . '"  data-language="' . $languages[$i]['name'] 
                        . '" data-languageid="' . $languages[$i]['id'] . '"'
                      , false); 
          ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

My javascript file called inside the loop (a part)
But in my case it's does not work

this case works, I can see alert with the informations but message has no value

```
var languageName = $(this).data('language'); // Extraire la valeur de data-language

  if (typeof languageName !== 'undefined' && languageName !== 'undefined') { 
    var languageId = $(this).data('languageid'); // Extraire la valeur de data-languageId
    var productsName = '{ $ProductsAdmin->getProductsName($id, ' + languageId + ')} ';    
    var questionResponse = '{$this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', ['languageName' => "' + languageName + '", 'productsName' => "' + productsName + '"])}';
alert(questionResponse);
  }
 newButton.click(function() { // Ajouter un listener pour chaque bouton
    let message = questionResponse;
    ....
```

- the alert is like that :
- text defined in english : ==> 1st pop up
- text defined in french : ==> 2nd pop up

but `let message = questionResponse`  as not value

If I do that

var languageName = $(this).data('language'); // Extraire la valeur de data-language

```
  if (typeof languageName !== 'undefined' && languageName !== 'undefined') { 
    var languageId = $(this).data('languageid'); // Extraire la valeur de data-languageId
    var productsName = '{ $ProductsAdmin->getProductsName($id, ' + languageId + ')} ';    
    var questionResponse = '{$this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', ['languageName' => "' + languageName + '", 'productsName' => "' + productsName + '"])}';
  }

alert(questionResponse);

 newButton.click(function() { // Ajouter un listener pour chaque bouton
    let message = questionResponse; 
    ....
```

- the alert is like that :
- undefined ==> first pop up
- text defined in english : ==> 2nf pop up
- undefined ==> 3th pop up
- text defined in french : ==> 4th pop up

My loop must be just twice because I have just 2 languages,french and english

How to get the good value for this line

```
let message = questionResponse;
```

if the information is not enough I can give more.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### I think you have created a variable *inside* a block and are trying to access it from *outside*

```
  if (typeof languageName !== 'undefined' && languageName !== 'undefined') { 
    ...
    var questionResponse = '{$this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', ['languageName' => "' + languageName + '", 'productsName' => "' + productsName + '"])}';
    ...
  }
 newButton.click(function() { 
    let message = questionResponse; // This is another block
    ....
```

#### Try creating the variable earlier

```
  var questionResponse = null

  if (typeof languageName !== 'undefined' && languageName !== 'undefined') { 
    ...
    questionResponse = '{$this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', ['languageName' => "' + languageName + '", 'productsName' => "' + productsName + '"])}';
    ...
  }
 newButton.click(function() { 
    let message = questionResponse; 
    ....
```

Comment: I tried this, but nor working, it seems when the data is inside the language loop, I have data pushed with no value.